# how to use values from a dataframe in pandas for column names, and column names as values insdie the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

| num_ind | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | val1 | 2val1 |
| 10000 | val2 | 2val2 |
| 10000 | val3 | 2val6 |
| 10001 | val4 | 2val1 |
| 10001 | val5 | 2val6 |
| 10001 | val6 | 2val3 |

the output should be as follows

| num_ind | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | 2val1 | 2val2 | 2val6 | 2val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | col1 | col1 | col1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | col2 | col2 | col2 | NaN |
| 10001 | Nan | NaN | NaN | col1 | col1 | col1 | col2 | NaN | col2 | col2 |

is there a way to get this result without loops, some pandorable code to get this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.melt('num_ind').pivot('num_ind','value','variable')
print (df)
value   2val1 2val2 2val3 2val6  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
num_ind                                                            
10000    col2  col2   NaN  col2  col1  col1  col1   NaN   NaN   NaN
10001    col2   NaN  col2  col2   NaN   NaN   NaN  col1  col1  col1
```